how to access REST API in laravel 10?
I'm working on a project using laravel 10 that uses REST API but I'm getting a 404 not found error when I tried to test the url http://localhost/api/v1/continent with GET request in Postman.
this is my routes/api.php:
Route::prefix('v1')->name('v1.')->group(function() {
    Route::get('continent', function() {
        return 'get all continents';
    });
});

this is the code in my App/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/ContinentController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Models\Continent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContinentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $list = Continent::all();
        // dd($list);

        return response()->json($list);
    }
}

what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated.

fyi, your route is not using your controller but a closure

yes, I was going to use the controller but then I thought to test the route with something simpler, so I used a closure for testing purposes..

Can you access the route when you remove prefix and name?

How do you serve your project? Do other routes work? Are you certain http://localhost points to that project? Does the route show up in php artisan route:list?

Remove name. Try accessing without name

Can you do php artisan route:list just do double check how the route is being defined

@zlatan this is the result after I run php artisan route:list https://jsfiddle.net/dapidmini/un8e2mp1/ (I don't know where else to put it so I just used jsfiddle)

@dapidmini You can [edit] your question and post relevant info there.

@dapidmini based on that output, seems like your api/v1/continent is not defined at all, you just have continent url there. Maybe your api.php file is not loaded at all? Try to dd(); at the top of the file, just to see that file is being loaded indeed.

Check if you have a routes.php file in bootstrap/cache folder. If it is you can delete it or you can run command php artisan routes:clear or php artisan cache:clear.
The issue is happening because you might have cached your routes.

I don't see any routes.php in my project folder, and I already tried running those commands.. but the error still persists. any other ideas?

I've finally found the solution for this particular problem.. it turns out I have to access the API and the web page in different way (I'm using XAMPP).
so to access the API in Postman I use http://localhost:8000/api/v1/continents,
and to access the web page in a browser I need to use http://localhost/myproject/public/continent.
hope this helps someone with the same problem. thank you to all who have responded to my question and comments.
